# Angular issue in IntelliJ

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I am facing following issue while working on an angular component in IntelliJ.

[image: Angular issue in IntelliJ]

Why do I face it and how to solve it?

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: I guess because a question usually requires a minimal reproducible example, which is preferable not a screenshot. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your component is added to an `NgModule`, and that this module has either `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` imported. Either directly, or through a common module import.

Make sure to only import the `BrowserModule` once in your app though